# Does time stop when the astral form comes out?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange

In *Doctor Strange*, Dr. Strange uses his astral form to communicate with the doctor.

[image]

Dr. Strange uses his astral form s second time to find the ancient one's astral form at the hospital, when she is admitted.

This time, the time does stop when he uses it. Why is that?

[image]

Comment: I don't know if it stops completely, since the doctor is moving and helping him...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The time doesn't stop the second time. The ancient one says:

> ..and your body hasn't even hit the floor yet

Strange's body falls back when stepping into astral form, and we see lightning forming in the sky.

My best guess is that Strange is "closer" to his real form/real world the first time, since he has to talk to Christine. Also why things are affected from the fight and from the defibrillator.